# Create external JavaScript file and call it on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, d3.js

I'm using D3.js library to create example animation in the simple HTML5 canvas.

But I won't use `<script>` inside HTML code. I need to create a file and put it there. So, how may I call it in HTML code?

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/delaunayanimation.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <canvas id="canvas">
            //how to call javascript here?
        </canvas>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my script that I created as external (its name is delaunayanimation.js):

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    τ = 2 * Math.PI,
    gravity = .05;

var sample = poissonDiscSampler(width, height, 30),
    nodes = [{x: 0, y: 0}],
    s;

while (s = sample()) nodes.push(s);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes.slice())
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? -30 : -3000; })
    .on("tick", ticked)
    .start();

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

var root = nodes.shift();

root.fixed = true;

var links = voronoi.links(nodes);

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove", moved);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
    
function moved() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
}

function ticked() {
  force.resume();

  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.y += (node.cy - node.y) * gravity;
    node.x += (node.cx - node.x) * gravity;
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = links.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var link = links[i];
    context.moveTo(link.source.x, link.source.y);
    context.lineTo(link.target.x, link.target.y);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = "#bbb";
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    context.moveTo(node.x, node.y);
    context.arc(node.x, node.y, 2, 0, τ);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fill();
}

// Based on https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/
function poissonDiscSampler(width, height, radius) {
  var k = 30, // maximum number of samples before rejection
      radius2 = radius * radius,
      R = 3 * radius2,
      cellSize = radius * Math.SQRT1_2,
      gridWidth = Math.ceil(width / cellSize),
      gridHeight = Math.ceil(height / cellSize),
      grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight),
      queue = [],
      queueSize = 0,
      sampleSize = 0;

  return function() {
    if (!sampleSize) return sample(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

    // Pick a random existing sample and remove it from the queue.
    while (queueSize) {
      var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
          s = queue[i];

      // Make a new candidate between [radius, 2 * radius] from the existing sample.
      for (var j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        var a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(),
            r = Math.sqrt(Math.random() * R + radius2),
            x = s.x + r * Math.cos(a),
            y = s.y + r * Math.sin(a);

        // Reject candidates that are outside the allowed extent,
        // or closer than 2 * radius to any existing sample.
        if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height && far(x, y)) return sample(x, y);
      }

      queue[i] = queue[--queueSize];
      queue.length = queueSize;
    }
  };

  function far(x, y) {
    var i = x / cellSize | 0,
        j = y / cellSize | 0,
        i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
        j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
        i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
        j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

    for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
      var o = j * gridWidth;
      for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
        if (s = grid[o + i]) {
          var s,
              dx = s.x - x,
              dy = s.y - y;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  function sample(x, y) {
    var s = {x: x, y: y, cx: x, cy: y};
    queue.push(s);
    grid[gridWidth * (y / cellSize | 0) + (x / cellSize | 0)] = s;
    ++sampleSize;
    ++queueSize;
    return s;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido  I need it to render an animation inside the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to append a `<canvas>` inside a `<canvas>`, which is pointless. This line:

```
var canvas = d3.select("#canvas").append("canvas")
```

looks for an element with ID "canvas" and append a `<canvas>` inside it. But in your HTML, that element is a canvas:

```
<section>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
</section>
```

If you just change this to a `<div>`, for instance:

```
<section>
    <div id="canvas">
    </div>
</section>
```

your code will work. Here is a working fiddle to show you (the only thing I did was the above mentioned change): https://jsfiddle.net/vcg1pk9v/1/

Also, have Spencer's answer in mind: the code that manipulates that div has to come *after* that div is created (in JSFiddle, the code will run after automatically). A good practice is putting it (or calling it, if external) just before closing the `<body>`. That being said, your question has actually **two** problems; Spencer dealt with one of them, I dealt with the other.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Instead `<canvas>` element, I changed to `<div>` and call external file after this declaration, however before `</body>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wait for the items such as the canvas to load in the DOM before running your code. You can either keep it in the `<head>` tag and wrap your code in [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or you can move it to the bottom of the body like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <canvas id="canvas">
            //how to call javascript here?
        </canvas>
    </section>
    <script src="js/delaunayanimation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't works. Shouldn't I call function inside canvas?

Comment: @coreid No, the HTML inside your canvas is just for displaying a fallback message if a browser doesn't support it. You need to call this after the canvas is defined, it doesn't matter when you call it as long as when that code is called the canvas element exist. If it doesn't work make sure you code is running and the JS is loading, and check the console for errors.

Comment: The js code is loading, but nothing is rendered if I put the whole code inside html it works, but not as external js file.

Comment: @coreid It works in exactly the same way if it was external or directly entered JavaScript. They only time it would not is if the JS code did not load, as in it's not being linked to correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Hey just call it after you have defined your canvas and that all.

Using `<script src="script path here"></script>`

Comment: Where is the rest of this?

Comment: use to load it in footer